# How to combine 2 schemas with a compound vocabulary document

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I had to create a compound XML document combining elements and attributes from both vocabularies made. The I need to create a combined schema for the compound document and confirm that the compound document passes validation. I put the the two vocabulary documents into one. I am unsure how to create a combined schema.

```
<!--Vocabulary1S
-->

<reg:smartphones xmlns:reg="http://example.com/smartphones/vocab"
                 reg:schemaLocation="http://example.com/smartphones/vocab/ns vocab1schema.xsd">

   <reg:choices>Smart Phones

      <reg:phones>

<!-- skip-->
 <!--Vocabulary2 -->

<plu:smartphones xmlns:plu="http://example.com/smartphones/vocab"
                 plu:schemaLocation="http://example.com/smartphones/vocab/ns vocab2schema.xsd">

<plu:pluschoices>Plus Size Choices

   <plu:bigphones>
      <plu:bigphone>

<!-- not complete code, end of doc-->

<!--start of combined schema Vocab1Schema -->

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:cc="http://example.com/smartphones/vocab/ns"
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/smartphones/vocab/ns"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

   <xs:element name="SmartPhones">

<!-- Vocab2Schema -->

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/smartphones/vocab/ns"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
>

<xs:element name="SmartPhones">
   <xs:complexType mixed="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your two schema documents contain definitions with the same targetNamespace, then you can create a combined schema simply using

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="...">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="schema1.xsd"/>
  <xs:include schemaLocation="schema2.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

This will give you an error if you have conflicting definitions, for example if the two schema documents contain conflicting definitions of the "SmartPhones" element. There is no way to combine the two schemas (or to reference them both in the same instance document) if they have conflicts like that; you would have to transform one of the instance documents and one of the schemas into a different namespace first.